# How to prove these two vectors are orthogonal?

Tags: matrices, vectors, projection-matrices

Let $$Q = I - 2\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}$$
And let $y$ be any vector orthogonal to $v$, and $x$ be any vector. Show that $x − Qx$ is
orthogonal to $y$, i.e. $Q$ projects through any vector that is orthogonal to $v$.

I have done this so far, and don't know what to do next:
$$\begin{align}
&(x − Qx)y\\
&=[x - (I - 2\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv})x]y\\
&=x - xI + 2x\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}y\\
&=2x\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}y\\
&= ?
\end{align}$$

I know I have to prove $(x − Qx)y=I$, but I son't know what to do next, when I reached here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Show that $x−Qx$ is orthogonal to $y$
>
> $\vdots$
>
> I know I have to prove $(x − Qx)y=I$.

Wrong. $x-Qx$ is orthogonal to $y$ if $(x-Qx)^Ty=0$ and you are almost done. You still need to use that $y$ is orthogonal to $v$, which means $v^Ty=0$. This yields
\begin{align}
(x-Qx)^Ty=\ldots=2x^T\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}y=\frac{2}{v^Tv}x^Tv\overbrace{v^Ty}^{=0}=0.
\end{align}

Comment: So, if it's matrix, then $AA^T=I$, for vector it's equals to 0 ?

Comment: It should be defined in your lecture that two vectors $x$ and $y$ are orthogonal if $x^Ty=0$. A quadratic matrix $A$ is called orthogonal if its columns are orthonormal to each other which means if $a_i$ is the $i$.th column of $A$ and $a_j$ the $j$.th column then $a_i^Ta_j=0$ if $i\neq j$ and $a_i^Ta_i=1$. This implies the equation $AA^T=I$.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I think I understand.